# Whats an elegant way of changing fetch address based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my backend does queryset filtering against the url parameters. On my frontend, depending whether a checkbox is ticked or not i wanna add a string (for example "?category=cardgame") to the axios url. Im not too sure how to do it

i was thinking of something like

```
 button1ticked && (url += string-associated-with-button1)
```

but idk how to actually write it in react. I know its a beginner question but thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use [The WHATWG URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#the-whatwg-url-api)

You can use the [*urlSearchParams.set(name, value)*](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlsearchparamssetname-value)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

function CheckBox({ name, onChange, category, initialState = false }) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(initialState);

  function handleOnChange(event) {
    const isChecked = !!event.target.checked;
    setIsChecked(isChecked);

    if (onChange) onChange(isChecked, { category: category });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        name={name}
        checked={isChecked}
        type="checkbox"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5");

  function onChange(checked, filter) {
    getList(filter, checked);
  }

  function buildUrl(filter, addFilter) {
    let newUrl = new URL(url);
    if (filter) {
      Object.keys(filter).forEach((key) => {
        if (addFilter) {
          newUrl.searchParams.set(key, filter[key]); // append param
        } else {
          newUrl.searchParams.delete(key);   // remove param
        }
      });
    }
    return newUrl.toString();
  }

  function getList(filter, addFilter) {
    const newURL = buildUrl(filter, addFilter);
    setUrl(newURL);
    axios
    .get(newURL)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .then(users => {
      this.setState({
        users,
        isLoading: false
      });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getList(null, false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CheckBox
        onChange={onChange}
        category="cardgame"
        name="check-box-name"
        initialState={true}
      />{" "}
      Checkbox 1
      <CheckBox
        onChange={onChange}
        category="boardgame"
        name="check-box-name"
        initialState={true}
      />{" "}
      Checkbox 2
      <CheckBox
        onChange={onChange}
        category="videogame"
        name="check-box-name"
        initialState={true}
      />{" "}
      Checkbox 3
    </div>
  );
}
```